# Nifi API - Update parameter context

Tags: api, parameter-passing, apache-nifi

We've created a parameter context within Nifi which is allocated to several process groups. We would like to update the value of one parameter within the parameter context. Is there any option to do this via the API?

Answer (score 1):

NiFi CLI from nifi-toolkit has commands for interacting with parameters, there is one for set-param:

https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/master/nifi-toolkit/nifi-toolkit-cli/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/toolkit/cli/impl/command/nifi/params

You could use that, or look at the code to see how it uses the API.

Also, anything you can do from NiFi UI has go through the REST API. So you can always open Chrome Dev Tools, take some action in the UI like updating a parameter, and then look at which calls are made.

Comment: Can you please help with commands or examples on how to update existing parameter context.. the above link doesn't show any commands or I am missing something.. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html also doesn't mention about updating existing parameter contexts. Can you Please help..

Comment: Never mind. used help to figure it out. $ nifi set-param -h .

$nifi set-param -pcid abc -pn <name> -pv <value> -ps <true/false for senstivity>